# Raise an event when click on FastReport open source toolbar Print button

Tags: asp.net-core, fastreport

In a .NET Core 6 web application, I am using FastReport to generate invoices.

Everything is working as expected. The invoices are generating and displaying on webpage successfully.

I just want to know how can I raise an event when FastReport toolbar print button is clicked so that I can insert invoice print date etc. to database.

Comment: Could you please share about  your scenario in more details. In addition, it would b great if you could include minimum reproducible sample.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.